# Second Job in a Chain of mapreduce jobs is not terminating in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm writing mapreduce program in hadoop to find a phrase in a set of files. I'm using a chain of 2 mapreduce jobs. But the problem is, the second job is not terminating. It is showing "reducer task executor complete" as shown below. But it is not getting terminated.

```
16/10/15 19:04:16 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1574338353_0002_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
16/10/15 19:04:16 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 1 / 1 copied.
16/10/15 19:04:16 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local1574338353_0002_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
16/10/15 19:04:16 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local1574338353_0002_r_000000_0' to hdfs://localhost:54310/gopal/output/_temporary/0/task_local1574338353_0002_r_000000
16/10/15 19:04:16 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/10/15 19:04:16 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1574338353_0002_r_000000_0' done.
16/10/15 19:04:16 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1574338353_0002_r_000000_0
16/10/15 19:04:16 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce task executor complete.
```

Here is my Code.

```
public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception
{

    Configuration conf = getConf();
    conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ";");
    System.out.println("********* First Job Started **********");

    JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, WordCount.class);           


    Path in = new Path(arg0[0]);
    Path out = new Path("/gopal/temp");


    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, in);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

    job.setJobName("Inverted Index");       

    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(MyPair.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(MyArrayWritable.class);

    String phrase = "";
    phrase = phrase + "Sachin " + "Tendulkar";

    JobConf job2 = null;

    System.out.println("Time taken by first map task: "+elapsedTime1);  
    System.out.println("Time taken by first reduce task: "+elapsedTime2);

    System.out.println("********* Second Job Started **********");

    Configuration conf2 = getConf();

    job2 = new JobConf(conf2, WordCount.class);

    Path out2 = new Path(arg0[1]);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, out);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, out2);

    job2.setJobName("SearchQuery Mapper");

    job2.set("PhraseSearch", phrase);   


    job2.setMapperClass( QuerySearchMapper.class);
    job2.setReducerClass( QuerySearchReducer.class);

    job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job2.setMapOutputValueClass(MyArrayWritable.class); 

    job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(MyArrayWritable.class);

    Job j1 = new Job(job);
    Job j2 = new Job(job2);

    JobControl jbcntrl = new JobControl ("jbcntrl");

    jbcntrl.addJob(j1);
    jbcntrl.addJob(j2);

    j2.addDependingJob(j1); 
    jbcntrl.run();          

    System.out.println("********* Second Job Completed**********");     

    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    if (args.length != 2)
    {
      System.err.println("Enter valid number of arguments <Inputdirectory>  <Outputlocation>");
      System.exit(0);
    }

    int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WordCount(), args);
    System.exit(res);
}
```

The message **Second Job Completed** is not getting printed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. I used below mentioned code to solve the problem. Using this we are adding waiting time for Job Control. It waits for that time duration and than terminated.

```
public class JobHandler {

    public static void handleRun(JobControl control) {
        JobRunner runner = new JobRunner(control);
        Thread t = new Thread(runner);
        t.start();

        while (!control.allFinished()) {
            System.out.println("Still running...");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}


JobHandler.handleRun(jobControl);
```